# How to make VIM receive and display the output of a program it is running?

Tags: linux, vim, terminal

When I run an interactive program using VIM, for example with:

```
:!node server.js
:!python my_app.py
```

The messages displayed by that program via `console.log`, `print` etc., will only be shown on vim when the program's process terminates, in a single chunk. This is different from running them directly on the terminal, where the messages are shown in real time. How to fix this behavior?

Comment: Most likely the output is buffered since it doesn't think its necessary to be seen. Is there any reason you are trying to run an interactive program from vim?

Comment: Could you provide more details? I do not see this behavior neither in terminal vim (where programs run with `!` use terminal directly and thus their behavior does not differ in a tiny bit from running them from shell) nor in `gvim` (testing with `:!echo 0 ; sleep 1 ; echo 2`). In the last case apps are not run in the terminal thus their behavior may differ. If `:!echo 0 ; sleep 1 ; echo 2` test shows that 0 and 2 are displayed with 1 second interval (first immediately), then you should ask developers of apps you run.

Comment: @FDinoff It is not necessary to run interactive program to want to know the output immediately: e.g. in case you run build script you may want to abort building on early seen error, fix it and rerun. Also note that in terminal vim running interactive app is perfectly fine since underlying terminal is used. In gvim this is also possible. This makes sense if you write a plugin that has to run this interactive script for some reason: in a plugin you cannot switch to shell with `<C-z>`/`:suspend` and run something there (you in fact can switch, but you cannot run).

Answer (score 1):

With vim 8's termimal feature, you can just do `:term node server.js` or `:term python my_app.py`.

See `:help :terminal` for more goodies.